# When using %s to set text in my path it will not find it

Tags: c, path, sdl-2, sdl-image

I am currently trying to read from multiple directories, but when I set the path using a %s (has a saved array of all the file locations) it will not read.

```
SDL_Surface* image = SDL_LoadBMP("D:\\UltimateModManager\\mods\\%s\\.umm\\icon.bmp", currentmod[i - 1]);
```

It prints the location just fine onto the console, yet it will not read my image. But if I set a true path, it does oddly enough.

Comment: Not enough info. No idea what you're trying to achieve. A quick search shows me that `SDL_LoadBMP` takes only one `const char*` parameter.

Comment: @DeiDei: I think it's pretty clear what OP is trying to do; it's just not how the language works,

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a misconception that `%s` in a string has some special property. It doesn't. The `%` character is just a literal `%`. The context in which you've used it the way you seem to want is passing it to `printf`, where it's *still just a literal `%` in the string, but the string is a *format string* that `printf` interprets to know what types of arguments to expect and how to format them, rather than a string to be printed itself.

To achieve what you want here, you need to use an additional buffer array to construct your string in, and use something like:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf,
         "D:\\UltimateModManager\\mods\\%s\\.umm\\icon.bmp",
         currentmod[i - 1]);
```

then pass `buf` as the argument to `SDL_LoadBMP`.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose the system reads it as is then, it makes sence